# Recurrence Relation when n is a fraction?

Tags: recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

If I have the following: $$T(n) = T(n/2) + 3$$

Where $n > 1$ and $T(1) = 2$, how do can I solve for odd $n$ values (e.g. $T(3) = T(3/2) + 3$)
?

Comment: In fact, your sequence is not well defined.

Comment: Get around that by writing $T(2n) = T(n) + 3$ instead. So now you can see that $T(n)$ is only defined for $n=1,2,4,8,16,\ldots$.

Comment: Often people mean the division to use rounding, either down or up.  The problem setter should specify if they want the recurrence to be well defined.  In this case if you round down then $T(n)$ will be constant for all values $2^k\le n \lt 2^{k+1}$

Comment: @MPW But that workaround dodges the OP’s question of $n=3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, $2^k\le n< 2^{k+1}$. Then, $\frac{n}{2^k}=1+e,0\le e<1$, where, $k=\log_2{n}$. $$\begin{align}T(n)& =T(n/2)+3\\ &=T(n/4)+3+3=T(n/4)+2\cdot 3\\ &=T(n/8)+3\cdot3=T(n/2^3)+3\cdot 3\\ &\vdots\\ &=T(n/2^k)+k\cdot 3=T(1+e)+3\log_2{n}\\&\le c\cdot T(1)+3\log_2{n}=2c+3\log_2{n}\\&=\mathcal{O}(\log_2{n})\end{align}$$

where $c$ is a constant.

**Note**: Usually, as you have used the tag [discrete-math](/questions/tagged/discrete-math), this type of recurrence relations come up in computing complexity of an algorithm, where length of input $n$ is always an integer.

Comment: Is this using the "Master Method"?

Comment: No, this is just straight forward calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You should suppose $n = 2^k$. Now you can solve it easily. Hence, $T(n) = 3(\log(n)-1) + 2 = 3\log(n) + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write it as
$T(n) = T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + 3
$.

This allows you to
write the cases
for even and odd $n$ as
$T(2n)=T(n)+3
$
and
$T(2n+1)=T(n)+3
$.